# v-for checkbox value in child component as prop (array of objects)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, nested-loops, v-for

I have two components 'Parent' and 'Child'. Each child component has checkbox with :checked prop. In Parent component I iterate through array of object and pass props to child. I can emit event from child back to parent and reassign new value in array, I see changes but the component doesn't re-renders.

What I am trying to do is to get some kinda radio group behaviour but within checkboxes. When one checkbox is clicked others need to be set as false. I can see clearly array has been modified but component doesn't re-renders (

Here's sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-starter-forked-jxgf9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**Parent component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Child
      v-for="l in list"
      :id="l.id"
      :key="l.id"
      :title="l.title"
      :checked="l.checked"
      @checked="handleUpdate"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "../components/Child.vue";

export default {
  name: "parent",
  components: {
    Child
  },
  data: () => ({
    list: [
      { title: "First", checked: false, id: "01" },
      { title: "Second", checked: false, id: "02" },
      { title: "Third", checked: false, id: "03" },
      { title: "Fourth", checked: false, id: "04" },
      { title: "Fifth", checked: false, id: "05" }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    handleUpdate(e) {
      const newArray = this.list.map(a => ({ ...a }));
      console.log(newArray);

      newArray.forEach(el => {
        if (el.id === e) {
          el.checked = true;
        } else {
          el.checked = false;
        }
      });

      this.list = [];
      this.list = newArray;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Child Component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" :value="checked" @click="$emit('checked', id)">
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "child",
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    checked: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Any help is highly appreciated guys. I really stuck on this and I'm stressed out (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN: Checkbox: Additional attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox),

```
Attribute        Description
checked          Boolean; if present, the checkbox is toggled on by default
indeterminate    A Boolean which, if present, indicates that the value of the checkbox is indeterminate rather than true or false
value            The string to use as the value of the checkbox when submitting the form, if the checkbox is currently toggled on
```

So in your codes, `v-bind:value` for `<input type="checkbox">` inside **child.vue** will not toggle the checkbox, it only changes the value of checkbox when submitting the form.

From [Vue Guide:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage): it states below:

> v-model internally uses different properties and emits different
> events for different input elements:
>
> **text and textarea elements** use value property and input event;
>
> **checkboxes and radiobuttons** use **checked** property and **change** event;
>
> **select fields** use value as a prop and change as an event.

That is the way how `v-model` works.

So in **child.vue**, uses:

`<input type="checkbox" :checked="checked" @click="$emit('checked', id)">`

[Updated Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-starter-forked-oom3m)

Comment: Sorry for delay. I have updated my post with a little explanation. What I wanted to do is to get behaviour like radio group but within a group of checkbox. When some of checkboxes is checked others should get unchecked.

Comment: check the updated **CodeSandBox** in the answer, after fixes the binding issue, it works as what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make the `Child` component work with `v-model` by using a computed with a getter and a setter. I forked your sandbox and made an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-starter-forked-weyzd .