# Vue js - How to append array data type using v-model from child components

Tags: vue.js

### Problem Description

I am trying to modularize my project and wondering how can I append an array data type within a parent component, using `v-model` along checkbox child components.

#### Expected Behaviour

[image]

#### Current Behaviour

[image]

#### Parent

```
<template>
    <h1> {{gameModes}}</h1>
    <Child v-for="(value, index) in gameModesNames"  
                v-bind:key="index"  
                :name="value"
                v-model="gameModes[index]"
                />
</template>

<script>
import Child from './Child.vue';

export default {

    component: { Child },
    data() {
        gameModes: [],
        gameModeNames: ["bullet" ,"blitz" , "rapid"]
    }
}
</script>
```

#### Child

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" :id="name" :value="name" 
           @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"/>
        <label :for="name">{{name}}</label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './Child.vue';

export default {

    props: {
      name: String
    },
    data() {}
}
</script>
```

---

#### Things I have tried

I have read thoroughly the Vue documentation on this matter but I can't seem to make it work. I have read posts on this SO with almost all solutions having the same format, in which the `v-model` variable is the same as the `value` variable, in my case it must be the array it self to append.

I have further tried to modify the `v-model` to `v-model:"value"`, `v-model:"name"` and `v-model:"gameModesNames"` but none work.

Does anyone know how to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63909868/v-for-checkbox-value-in-child-component-as-prop-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

In the parent component you need to catch the event that is being emited (`@input`) and trigger a method afterwise. So `@input="doThis(indexOrEvent)"`  inside `doThis` you push the element to the array.

Also I think that the correct event should be `@clicked` but Im not sure so I don't want to give an strong opinion on that topic